# difference between two bind usage

Tags: javascript

I'm practicing `bind` in javascript and meet one problem.

```
var test = {
  val: 1
}
function bindTest () {
  console.log(this.val)
}
bindTest.bind(test)()
```

In this little demo, I get 1 as result as it should return.

However, when i try to use bind on event handler, bind won't work.
For example

```
var container = document.querySelector('.container'),
    test = {val: 1}
function bindTest (event) {
  console.log(this.val)
}
container.addEventListener('click', bindTest.bind(test))
```

In this case, `this` in bindTest become `window`. I know that bind is used to create a new function which `this point to its bind object`. Why i get different answer after applying to an event handler?

Comment: doesn't seem to be. second is also working fine.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are you sure this is the code?

Comment: Sorry, guys. To simpily the question i make this example. And i have fixed the question  with real code. Sorry and thanks @Jai

Comment: To be honest, I didn't know what happened that my code truely work  correctly. Sorry for wasting your time, Thanks agian@dloeda

Answer (score 0):

add bracket after bindTest.bind(test)

```
var container = document.querySelector('.container'),
    test = {val: 1}
function bindTest () {
  console.log(this.val)
}
container.addEventListener('click', bindTest.bind(test)())
```

both cases we will get the answer 1.

Comment: I don't think so , bindTest.bind() will return a funciton as event handler.But` `bindTest.bind(test)()` will excute it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting your time to view this stupid question. I have no idea about what i have done that my code work correctly now. I need to debug to find the reason.

So  the  conclusion is that  You **can**  use `bind` method in this scene.

Thanks again!